# php: fatal error out of memory allocated

Tags: php

На одном достаточно сильном скрипте (много памяти требует) сайт стал кидать ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated x) (tried to allocate n bytes)
```

Поставил с запасом

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

Но все равно та же ошибка.

top выдает

```
Mem: ... total, .... used, 53456k free, ... buffers
```

Comment: Вероятно, скрипт просто течет. Советую в таких случаях использовать [профайлер](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler).

Comment: Если вам все таки действительно надо много памяти, то сделайте `memory_limit=-1`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте писать скрипты так, чтобы они не требовали 200Мб памяти для работы, ведь весь этот вагон памяти накапливается в процессе работы. Поэтому проверьте свой PHP-скрипт на наличие утечек памяти, используя гениальный фреймворк [W3AF](http://w3af.sourceforge.net/) для тестирования и проверки своего скрипта с уймой подключаемых модулей( (которых около ста(!)) в том числе и для проверки скрипта на течи )